# Using multiple GCP Datastore namespaces with Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, spring-data

I have 2 Spring projects using the the following dependency:

> com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore

Project A (runnable jar) depends on project B (library) and both are using Spring Data Repositories for GCP Datastore persistence.

I need to use different Datastore namespaces for the 2 projects.

Only thing I can think of makes use of DatastoreNamespaceProvider, but I can't figure out how I can use different namespaces for different projects / repositories / packages:

```
   @Bean
   fun datastoreNamespaceProvider(): DatastoreNamespaceProvider {
        return DatastoreNamespaceProvider {
            if (???) {
                datastoreNamespace2
            } else {
                datastoreNamespace1
            }
        }
    }
```